# How to count the number of consecutively repeated characters in a string

Tags: go

Basically, what I want to achieve is to not allow passwords with lots of consecutively repeated chars/digits.
I'm trying to write a **go** function to which I pass a string and a maximum allowed number of consecutively repeated characters, and it should tell me if it's surpassed or not.

I used to do it easily in **javascript** using the a regular expression in the following way:

```
var regexString = '(.)\\1{' + (maxAllowedRepetitions) + ',}';
var regex = new RegExp(regexString);
return regex.test(string)
```

... where maxAllowedRepetitions is the max limit. If the limit is 3 and a string is 'blablabla', it returns `false`. If it is blablaaaabla, it returns `true` since the character 'a' is repeated more than 3 times.

I'm finding it difficult to achieve the same thing using **go** regexp.
I don't mind not using regexp. I just need a good way to achieve this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Rather than use backreferences, which aren't supported in go, and can be much less efficient, just use a for loop and a counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/HeK3f4uEvz

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    // invalid password with repetition
    password := "blablaaaabla"
    fmt.Printf("%s invalid ? %+v\n", password, invalid(password))

    // correct password with no repetition
    password = "blabla"
    fmt.Printf("%s invalid ? %+v\n", password, invalid(password))

    // valid password with unicode character
    password = "bla∞∞bla"
    fmt.Printf("%s invalid ? %+v\n", password, invalid(password))

    // invalid password with unicode character
    password = "bla∞∞∞bla"
    fmt.Printf("%s invalid ? %+v\n", password, invalid(password))
}

func invalid(s string) bool {
    var lastChar rune
    var lastCharCount = 0
    for _, c := range s {
        if c == lastChar {
            lastCharCount++
            if lastCharCount >= 3 {
                return true
            }
        } else {
            lastChar = c
            lastCharCount = 1
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

results

```
blablaaaabla invalid ? true
blabla invalid ? false
bla∞∞bla invalid ? false
bla∞∞∞bla invalid ? true
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
func AbideMaxRepetitions(max int, s string) bool {
    var rr rune
    rc := 0
    for _, r := range s {
        if rr == r {
            rc++
            if rc > max {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            rr = r
            rc = 1
        }

    }
    return true
}
```

When running:

```
func main() {
    ss := []string{"pass", "paaass", "paaaaaaaaaass", "ppa", "pppa", "x", "xx", "xxx"}
    for _, s := range ss {
        fmt.Printf("%q: %v\n", s, AbideMaxRepetitions(2, s))
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
"pass": true
"paaass": false
"paaaaaaaaaass": false
"ppa": true
"pppa": false
"x": true
"xx": true
"xxx": false
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop should do the trick. Just remember that Go uses UTF8 for strings. You need to compare Runes (character) not bytes.